# Disable SUBMIT on ENTER - script not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried a few suggestions from this site on preventing SUBMIT when the user presses the ENTER key on a form, but they don't seem to work. I'm either not putting the SCRIPT in the correct place or maybe it's because I'm using a MODAL?

Here's one of the scripts I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js">
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $(window).keydown(function(event){
                if(event.keyCode == 13) {
                 event.preventDefault();
                  return false;
                }
              });
             });
</script>
```

I've put the code after the FORM tags, nested it in the BUTTON SUBMIT tags. Where am I going wrong? The form is a simple form with inputs and selects with some PHP to populate the select tags.

Comment: I recommend declaring jquery as a separate script and then just using `<script>//your code</script>`

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs - I'm not sure what you mean by declaring it as a separate script?

Comment: so declare one script like `<script src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>` then another like `<script>$(document) //rest of code</script>` - keeps the code clean and easier to manage :)

Comment: Winner Winner Chicken Dinner!! - Thanks @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs - that worked... yes, I play PUBG :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there is `src` attribute in `<script>` any content inside tag is ignored. ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-src))

You have to create two tags. One for jQuery CDN and one for your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).keydown(function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining about the code inside the SRC tag being ignored...

Comment: I wanted to mark this but you gave me the correct answer first so I was a bit hesitant. I have marked it now...

Comment: @Rayza I only commented :) don't worry bout it ;) :)